# Formally specify the languages defined by the following regular expressions

Tags: compiler-construction, expression, regular-language

I am studying for an exam in the morning using a past exam provided by the professor without solutions. Unfortunately I missed the day the exam was solved in class and therefore can't figure out how to do this set. I have spent the past hour searching google for a clear explanation and can't seem to understand. I will list the problem exactly. My main questions are what makes a language definition formal, and why aren't the expressions listed already considered the language? I hope this makes sense, I have been up for way too many hours looking at this.

Formally specify the languages defined by the following regular expressions. If you provide regular expressions, please be sure to reduce them to their simplest forms.

(a) (11|111)*

(b) (ε|φ*1|0φ)+

(c) (0|1)* |1*

If you could help with any of these and explain the process I can do the rest. Thank a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be something like, for (a), "Either an empty string or a sequence of n 1s where n >= 2."

Comment: I would certainly describe (a) in that way, but is that considered a"formal specification"?

Comment: That's all I could guess, although it's possible I'm wrong. I think the description of *formal* specification, as opposed to (say) "informal description" is to indicate you can't leave any ambiguity. For example, "it doesn't include the string '1'" could be considered an "informal description."